# How do I return the index of a list by giving it a specific integer in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

one of my assignments is to write a function that accepts two arguments, a list and an integer, and returns the specified element of the list. So, for example, if you give it a list x and the number 2, it would return the second element of the list x. My teacher wants us to do this without using any of the list methods. However, the arguments can't seem to pass through. Is there a way I can declare a variable then initialize it later? I don't know how to get around this.

```
myList = [1, 3, 'hello', 6, 8]

int num

def find_element(myList, num):
    return myList[num]
print(myList[num])
```

Comment: Does your assignment perhaps want the number to come from standard input?

Comment: "without using any of the list methods": I don't understand that. Perhaps it's useful to learn something about algorithms, but even looping through a list would require using the `__next__` method (iterating over its elements) or the `__len__` method (for creating an old-fashioned `for i in range(0, len(myList))` loop).

Comment: Also: "However, the arguments can't seem to pass through". But you never call your function in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask a user to input a value via `input()` in Python 3 [or `raw_input()` in Python 2]. 
You could use that as the index to retrieve. But that input does come in as a string, so you would have to convert it to an integer.  You could do something like this:

```
def find_element(myList, num):
    return myList[num]

myList = [1, 3, 'hello', 6, 8]

val = input('Please enter an index between 0 and 4: ')
num = int(val)

print(find_element(myList, num))
```

Note that you've written your function to use the same variable names that are used in the main program.  This is okay, but it can be a little confusing as to what's going on.  You can (and probably should) use different variable names to make it more obvious what's happening. So, for instance, you could do your function as:

```
def find_element(someList, someNum):
    return someList[someNum]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [1,3,'hello',4,5,6,7]

def find_element(List, Num):
    return List[Num-1]
print(find_element(myList,2)) #Num will print what is contained in list in order
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1, 3, 'hello', 6, 8]
list2 = [4, 7, 'prevyet', 1, 'a']
list3 = [-99, 77, 'caio', 78, 3]

def find_element(theList, theNum):
    retVal = None
    if theNum >=0 and theNum < len(theList):
        retVal = theList[theNum]
    return retVal

print(find_element(list1, 3))
print(find_element(list2, 0))
print(find_element(list3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it can't to use any list method. maybe should to use a loop.

```
def func(arr, num):
    for key, value in enumerate(arr):
        if key == num:
            return value
    return None

my_list = [1, 3, 'hello', 6, 8]
print(my_list, 2)
```

If you want to input the num. just as the @Gary02127 says.

```
num = int(input("input the number: "))
```